# Search function using Jquery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview

i'm doing a search function on a gridview with Jquery 
i am able to hide the grid when entering text in the search box but the code does not validate the text on the gridview making it not able to search the rows 
my gridview is edited and can be selected to display a datalist so i'm not very sure how to make it work

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
    $('#<%=lblNoRecords1.ClientID%>').css('display','none'); 

    $('#<%=Button2.ClientID%>').click(function(e){
        $('#<%=lblNoRecords1.ClientID%>').css('display','none');
        $("#<%=GridView1.ClientID%> ").hide();

        var iCounter = 0; 
        var sSearchTerm = $('#<%=SearchBox1.ClientID%>').val();

        if (sSearchTerm.length == 0){ 
           $("#<%=GridView1.ClientID %> tr:has(td)").show(); 
           return false;
        } 

        $("<%=GridView1.ClientID%> tr:has(td)").children().each(function(){ 
           cellText = $(this).text().toLowerCase(); 
           if(cellText.indexOf(sSearchTerm.toLowerCase()) >=0){ 
               $(this).parent().show(); 
               iCounter++; 
               return true; 
           } 
       }); 
       if(iCounter == 0) 
       { 
            $('#<%=lblNoRecords1.ClientID%>').css('display','');
       } 
       e.preventDefault();
    })
  })
</script>
```

Comment: Please create a jsfiddle.net with rendered code

Comment: @mplungjan i don't know how to add the codes in is it possible to send the file instead

Comment: 1) view source of web page, 2) go to jsfiddle.net and paste relevant code 3) copy relevant code here too

Comment: You are missing a hash (#) on the selector `"<%=GridView1.ClientID%> tr:has(td)"`. Personally, for simplicity, if I want to reference something via JQuery set the ClientIdMode to static and then you can remove all of the references to Client ID. Makes the whole thing much easier to work with.